# Should I check insert count when using Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have the Users table and want to insert User in it and return `Ok` or `Error` to the frontend.

I thought that it's possible to have zero updates when inserting, so I always check for insert count like this:

```
 // Somewhere in userService
 def add(user: User): Future[Int] = db.run(users += user)
 ...
 // Routes
 onSuccess(add(newUser)) {
    case insertCount if insertCount == 1 =>
      complete(Ok)
    case _ =>
      complete(Error)
 }
```

But when reading Bootzooka code I find that they don't care about update count:

```
def add(user: User): Future[Unit] = db.run(users += user).mapToUnit
```

Should I care about insert count? Or does Future fails if there are no inserts?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not required. Slick throws exception if in case any insert statement fails.

You can safely ignore the returned int value.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I can write less code from this point! However, can you point me to docs / sources so I can understand it by myself? Or it's to complicated?